# Hyundai Santa Fe rear underbody cover

Tags: hyundai, underbody

I have rented Hyundai Santa Fe Sport in USA and today, while driving on a highway, I heard some weird sound. After examining the vehicle, I have found out, that the plastic cover under car, that is behind rear wheel and bumper is barely holding onto the car. I tried to find some manual on how to repair it (or at least secure it -  Im not near any car service station), but I have no idea what is the name of this part and if it can be somehow put back by me or not. Pictures included shows the part. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! More than likely it just needs some [plastic bumper clips](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0787W6KFS). Who knows why they'd be missing, but whatever. If the opposite side is not hanging down, you can probably see how it is affixed to the body and get this side in the same shape pretty easily.